# How to use 'Service' in an internet browser App

Tags: java, android

I am newbie so please forgive me for anything wrong that I am doing or if I am asking the question in the wrong way.

I recently created a simple media player on android studio and used Java Service to play the media when I closed the app and it works fine. Now I have created a simple web browser app using `WebView` and I want to use the same "Java Service" to keep my web browser app running even when it is minimized but I have no idea how to convert the media player code to use on the web browser app. I have researched a lot and nobody else seems to want to create a browser that keeps running in the background. Please can you assist me in solving this?

Because I am new to Java, it is difficult for me to try and convert the code from media player to web browser

So here is my media player code:

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button start, stop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStartService);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopService);


        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == start){
            startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        }else if(view == stop){
            stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();

        return START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        player.stop();
    }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity for the Webbrowser that I have created:

````
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView browser;
    EditText link;
    Button btn_visit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        link = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLink);
        btn_visit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_view);

        browser.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());

        btn_visit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url = link.getText().toString();
                browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                browser.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });
    }

    private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}

```

So now I need to create another MyService that will allow the webbrowser to run in the 
background but dont know how to go about it: 
```


public class MyService extends Service {



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }
}
````

As I said, there no errors that I am getting on the media player app. I just want to be able to use the same code on the internet browser app but don't know how to convert it.

Comment: A service isn't going to keep an Activity running when minimized in Android.  Android can kill any Activity that isn't in the foreground at any time for resources.  There's a mechanism (onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState) that gives you a chance to save any important data in case your Activity is restored to the foreground.  Use that to recover your state.

Comment: thanks for the response Gabe. One of the reasons i want the browser to keep running in the background is that if the user is playing my video or song in the browser, I want them to be able to keep hearing it while the browser is minimised. Is this not a possibility with Android?

Comment: The fact it's via a web browser makes it hard- you could use a service if it was native. But there's no way to force an activity to stay alive, and views need to be owned by the activity

Comment: okay I see, thanks for that help and advice Gabe. It is really appreciated.